# return means of likert scale data from counts

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So i am trying to get the means of likert scale data provided only with the counts and level of agreement. Here are my steps:

1. recode levels of agreement i.e., strongly disagree = 1; strongly agree = 5
2. multiple numeric agreement values by the number of occurences (i.e.,the number of times people said they agreed or disagreed with an item). Call this agreement_numeric
3. find the means of agreement_numeric and divide by the sum of agreement_numeric.
4. this should give me likert scale means, but it isnt. I am getting a mean of 0.05 for all items.

here is my dataset:

```
Year1_likert_exhibits <- structure(list(Item = c("Were informative and educational", "Were easy to read", 
"Covered topics I liked", "Were introduced in an informative way by staff", 
"Were informative and educational", "Were easy to read", "Covered topics I liked", 
"Were introduced in an informative way by staff", "Were informative and educational", 
"Were easy to read", "Covered topics I liked", "Were introduced in an informative way by staff", 
"Were informative and educational", "Were easy to read", "Covered topics I liked", 
"Were introduced in an informative way by staff", "Were informative and educational", 
"Were easy to read", "Covered topics I liked", "Were introduced in an informative way by staff"
), Evaluation = c("Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Somewhat agree", "Somewhat agree", "Somewhat agree", 
"Somewhat agree", "Neither agree nor disagree", "Neither agree nor disagree", 
"Neither agree nor disagree", "Neither agree nor disagree", "Somewhat disagree", 
"Somewhat disagree", "Somewhat disagree", "Somewhat disagree", 
"Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
"Strongly disagree"), Value = c(135, 136, 134, 122, 24, 21, 24, 
21, 3, 2, 4, 16, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4), percent = c(20, 20, 
20, 18, 4, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), level = c("5", 
"5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and here is the code:

```
Year1_likert_exhibits <- Year1_likert_exhibits %>%
  mutate(level = recode(Evaluation, `Strongly agree` = '5', `Somewhat agree` = '4', `Neither agree nor disagree` =  '3', `Somewhat disagree` = '2', `Strongly disagree` = '1'))
Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement <- Year1_likert_exhibits %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(agreement = as.numeric(level)*Value)
Year1_likert_exhibits_mean <- Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement%>%
  group_by(Item)%>%
  summarise(mean = (mean(Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement$agreement)/sum(Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement$agreement)))
View(Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement)
View(Year1_likert_exhibits_mean)
```

End goal: I want to display these mean on my chart, like this:
[image]

Comment: There is a least one issue with your code: Using `Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement$agreement` you get the mean and the sum for the ungrouped df. Do `mean(agreement)` and `sum(agreement)` to get mean and sum per Item.

Comment: returns the same issue, except all my means are .2 instead of .05

Comment: Not 100% sure about your desired result, but if you want to get the mean level then I would do `summarise(mean = sum(agreement) / sum(Value))`

Comment: I want a mean for each item. I updated the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comments the first issue with your code us that you use `Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement$...` and second that the your formula to get the mean level per item is wrong, i.e. you have to do `summarise(mean = sum(agreement) / sum(Value))`:

```
library(dplyr)

Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement <- Year1_likert_exhibits %>%
  mutate(agreement = as.numeric(level) * Value) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(mean = sum(agreement) / sum(Value), Value = sum(Value))

library(ggplot2)

fill_labels <- Year1_likert_exhibits %>% 
  select(level, Evaluation) %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  tibble::deframe()

pal_fill <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(12, "Paired")[c(2, 3, 11, 8, 6)]

ggplot(Year1_likert_exhibits, aes(Value, Item)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = level), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(data = Year1_likert_exhibits_agreement, 
            aes(label = paste0("Mean = ", sprintf("%.2f", mean))),
            hjust = 1, nudge_x = -2, fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill, labels = fill_labels, breaks = 5:1) +
  labs(fill = "Evaluation")
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to keep the legend labels the same, though. e.g. strongly agree

Comment: Well, the plot wasn't part of the question but I just added an edit to fix that.